# How to add a JS variable into a hidden form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having a problem trying to get a JS variable into a hidden field.

I'm currently getting the value I need like this:

```
HTML Snippet
<p class="total-box"><span></span></p>

JS Snippet
var totalDonation = $('.total-box > span');
```

This gives me what I need to display on the page, but I need to pass that value into a hidden form value.

I tried many approaches from SO and Google. Like this:

```
HTML Snippet
<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="xyz" value="">

JS Snippet:
document.getElementById('xyz').value = totalDonation;
```

No Luck.

Also thought about adding the hidden field using JS as that would work too like this:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "xyz");
input.setAttribute("value", ('value', document.querySelector('.total-box > span').innerText);

//append to form element that you want .
document.getElementById("xyz").appendChild(input);
```

I've been at this all day and can't see where I'm going wrong. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/maxrBo?editors=1011) of my code I'm working with.**

Comment: `totalDonation` is a jquery object, you're trying to set hidden field value to it, you need the value from it, not entire object

Comment: @Bob that's what I was trying in my first approach. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: `document.getElementById('xyz').value = totalDonation.text()`

Comment: You may want to consider choosing either the jQuery method of selecting and interacting with the DOM (e.g., `$('.total-box > span')`) or standard DOM methods (e.g. `document.querySelector(‘.total-box > span’)` ) and sticking with it consistently. It makes it easier to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this; the description is mentioned in the code snipp ; basically
get the inner text of the span tag and assign it to the hidden input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p class="total-box"><span>This is the text</span></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="xyz" /> 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

       var totalDonation = $(".total-box>span").text();

       $("#xyz").val(totalDonation); // Sets the text from total donation to your hidden input

       var hiddeninput = $("#xyz").val();

       console.log(hiddeninput); // displays hidden input data


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to set an input value to a jQuery object which is a span element. You need to use `.text()` to get the value of the span first. In this line:

```
var totalDonation = $('.total-box > span');
```

Just add `.text()` like so:

```
var totalDonation = $('.total-box > span').text();
```

And now it should work.

Comment: I tried doing as you said, but still not passing that value. The only value I'm getting is 0.00. See code pen here or in my updated question. https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/maxrBo?editors=1011